# Is it possible to do sums of aggregation that stops aggregating once the condition is reached?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

Say I have a table `amounts` with millions of rows tallying up to some number, but I'm really just checking if it's > 100. Is there a way to stop aggregation since taking this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM stored_value;
```

Into this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM stored_value
HAVING SUM(amount) > 100;
```

However this does not change anything on the amount of aggregation. Something that would work with date ranges.

Comment: So you want the smallest sum, that is larger than 100? And what's that with the date ranges? I don't see any dates/timestamps in your queries? Here's what you should do to improve your changes getting a good answer: Show the relevant part of the schema by editing your question and adding the respective `CREATE TABLE` statement(s). Also add some sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements for the tables. Finally add the expected result with that sample data.

Comment: sticky bit is right: we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what order your rows that contribute to the sum is in:

```
select * from (
    select ...n sum(amount) over () as sm
    from ...
    where ...
) as x
where sm > 100
```

If you do care about the order, you should add info on how the cumulative sum is calculated:

```
select * from (
    select ...n sum(amount) over (order by ...) as sm
    from ...
    where ...
) as x
where sm > 100
```

You may even sumarise per something like:

```
select * from (
    select ...n sum(amount) over (partition by ... 
                                  order by ...) as sm
    from ...
    where ...
) as x
where sm > 100
```

However, since you are talking about stopping, when the sum reaches something I suggest what you need is something like:

```
select * from (
    select ...n sum(amount) over (partition by ... 
                                  order by ...) as sm
    from ...
    where ...
) as x
where sm <= 100
```